# How can an IoS APP send email using Outlook

Tags: ios, apple-mail

We have an IoS APP that can send and email and attach a file that was created by the app.
It has worked fine for long but now a user says it is not possible. It seems like the users at this company are not allowed to use Apple Email so they are using Outlook.

I have now heard that the IoS APPs requires Apple Email to send emails. I just thought that was a bit strange and wanted to ask if there are ways so that the APP can use Outlook instead.

Comment: You can't use `MFMailComposeViewController` to send via outlook.  You could use `UIActivityViewController` to let the user share the file via Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Apps aren't required to use Apple's mail API, but if you want to use something else then you have to do it yourself. Apple won't stop you from using Outlook but they won't help you either. Outlook has its own [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) that can be used by third party apps. There are various [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535484/how-can-i-send-mail-in-office-365-rest-api) on StackOverflow from people using that API.