# Switching from SMTP to OAuth2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

This isn't a code specific question, but more of a general question regarding OAuth2.  I maintain a system that for the past 20+ years has been able to easily connect to any SMTP enabled email server, then send an email (only requiring authentication info and a server path).  This email account is always system related, and isn't specific to one user, such as support@.

With GMail and Office365 (and other major email providers) dropping support for SMTP direct sends, I have been learning OAuth2.  With all the reading I've done, OAuth2 is very email server specific (or so it seems).  But from a systems standpoint, I need to be able to send support email regardless of whom is logged into the system, and regardless of what email host, with no authentication popups.

Is a single solution even possible with OAuth2?  Will I need to code for every email provider differently? (GMail, Office365, etc)  (I can currently get an authorization token from Office 365, but it seems very specific to Office 365)  I have yet to figure out how to actually send an email through Office365 with my OAuth2 token, since MailKit doesn't seem to support OAuth.  Is there a single protocol that will allow me to send an OAuth2 token through any email host?

I understand how SMTP direct send has been abused for a long time, but replacing it sucks.

Comment: My company has setup SMTP Relays.  See : https://www.mailjet.com/blog/news/what-is-an-smtp-relay/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535484/how-can-i-send-mail-in-office-365-rest-api

Comment: The REST Api approach has been deprecated.  I am amazed how difficult this switch off of SMTP email is.